# How to sort string which appear in dataframe column?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe like data1. I want the string in Column C sorted and looks like below. Is there anyway?

```
b <- letters [1:5]
c <- c(rep ("1,3,2", 2), rep("1,54", 3))
data1 <- data.frame (b, c)
```

b   c
1 a 1,2,3
2 b 1,2,3
3 c 1,4,5
4 d 1,4,5
5 e 1,4,5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please provided an expected output.